# jQuery add/removeClass doesn't trigger CSS transitions for 'right' property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to have pre-built classes that I can swap in and out with jQuery, and thereby trigger animations with jQuery that are defined in the CSS. But for some reason, whenever I use addClass or removeClass such that it causes 'right' to go from -5% to 0%, there is no transition. The element's style immediately changes with no animation.

My HTML:

```
<body>
    <ol style="list-style-type:none">
        <li style="top: 20%;" id="about" class="pane closed hidden" onclick="function(event){}">about</li>
        <li style="top: 25%;" id="education" class="pane closed hidden">education</li>
        <li style="top: 30%;" id="experience" class="pane closed hidden">experience</li>
        <li style="top: 35%;" id="contact" class="pane closed hidden">contact</li>
    </ol>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
.pane {
    transition: opacity 400ms linear, width 80ms ease-in-out, right 200ms ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms linear, width 80ms ease-in-out, right 200ms ease-out;

    width: 5%;
    height: 3%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top:0.5%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: lightgray;
    overflow:hidden;
    right: 0%;
}
.pane.hidden {
    right: -5%;
}
.pane.closed {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.pane:hover {
    width: 8%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){$('#about').removeClass('hidden');}, 200);
    setTimeout(function(){$('#education').removeClass('hidden');}, 400);
    setTimeout(function(){$('#experience').removeClass('hidden');}, 600);
    setTimeout(function(){$('#contact').removeClass('hidden');}, 800);
});
```

For clarity, the class changes do happen in sequence spaced by 200ms, as setTimeout is supposed to do. The problem is that when they trigger, they appear immediately instead of sliding in.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/mzPGC/

Comment: It works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/FrtjA/ What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, but I experienced the same effect in firefox. I also just discovered that 'left' does the same thing. But for whatever reason, 'width' works just fine. Do you think it could have to do with my use of percentages?

Comment: That's so odd... It works for me too in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I had Twitter Bootstrap CSS included also. Apparently something in there was conflicting, which is why it worked in the jsFiddle. If I had to guess, it probably uses a class called "hidden" that was changing the transition value or something (something I should have thought of). Thanks for your time and effort, those who responded.